# How do you select a particular object from a django model and use it to retrieve a url? (CS50 Project 2)

Tags: python, django, django-models, href, cs50

I am doing CS50 Project 2 and have a django model called Listing that has an object called Category that the user can pick using a dropdown list. All the categories are listed on the categories page and need to link to the categories_page page that displays all the listings in that category. Can you help me with the href and variable for the categories page to link it to the categories_page page?

categories views.py

```
def categories(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/categories.html",{
        "Miscellaneous": Listings.objects.all().filter(category=Miscellaneous)
    })
```

categories.html (I need to link all the categories on this page to their own categories_page.)

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Categories</h1>

    <a href="{% url 'categories' Miscellaneous.category %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Miscellaneous</h5></a>
    <h5>Movies and Television</h5>
    <h5>Sports</h5>
    <h5>Arts and Crafts</h5>
    <h5>Clothing</h5>
    <h5>Books</h5>
{% endblock %}
```

categories_page views.py

```
def categories_page(request, category):
    listings = Listings.objects.all().filter(category=category)
    return render(request, "auctions/categories_page.html",{
        "listings": listings,
        "heading": category
    })
```

categories_page.html

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    {% for listing in listings %}
        <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);">
            <img src ="{{ listing.image }}" style = "height: 10%; width: 10%;">
            <h4 class = "text">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
            <h6>Description: {{ listing.description }}</h6>
            <h6>Category: {{ listing.category }}</h6> 
            <h6>Price: ${{ listing.bid }}</h6>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %
```

categories_page views and html both work. I am having trouble with the categories views and html.

Let me know if you need any more code. Thank you so much!

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .models import User, Listings
from .forms import ListingsForm
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
    path("categories", views.categories, name = "categories"),
    path("categories/<str:category>/", views.categories_page, name = "categories_page"),
    path("listing/<int:id>/", views.listing, name = "listing"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register")
]
```

models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
    ("Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous"),
    ("Movies and Television", "Movies and Television"),
    ("Sports", "Sports"),
    ("Arts and Crafts", "Arts and Crafts"),
    ("Clothing", "Clothing"),
    ("Books", "Books"),
]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000000000, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY, default=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not actually necessary to try to get the category object from the model. This code worked for me.

category.views

```
def categories(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/categories.html")
```

categories.html

```
<a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Miscellaneous' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Miscellaneous</h5></a>
    <a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Movies and Television' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Movies and Television</h5></a>
    <a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Sports' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Sports</h5></a>
    <a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Arts and Crafts' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Arts and Crafts</h5></a>
    <a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Clothing' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Clothing</h5></a>
    <a href="{% url 'categories_page' 'Books' %}" style = "color: rgb(58, 58, 58);"><h5>Books</h5></a>
```

All you have to do is put the name of the url then the name of the argument you want.

Comment: Hi.  What you're doing here is "hard-coding" values into your code, which is generally a bad idea.  Imagine you have a lot more categories, would you want to write a new `<a href=...` for each one?  A better approach is to iterate through them, as I showed in my answer.  When I saw your model, I realized you were using choices instead of a Foreign key.  No problem there, though with a ForeignKey you'd be able to add more categories making your code more flexible.  Either way, iterating through the categories is the way to go.  Did the code in my answer not work?

Comment: @raphael, no your answer didn't work.